# How to embed Python Machine learning model into NodeJs

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to deploy an python ML model into Nodejs web application to predict labels for the text data . I have used Tensorflowjs to import the predicted output into the Node but its not working . 
Now I am Looking to deploy the model in Node using the API.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/form.html'));
});
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const model = tf.loadLayersModel('C:\Users\Desktop\Prod\category\model.json');
```

**How I can Use the ML model using the API in Node Js**

Comment: @Why the Negative voting has been done . Is there anything wrong with the Question. ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer might be a little late..but

1. you should use FILE protocol(FILE://....) to load local models

also, you should require('@tfsjs-node') node in your script.